# Rate of Insertion decreases as property writeBehindEnbled is set to true

Tags: hbase, ignite

I am using Ignite's Cache adapter by setting write-through as true.

**Scenario 1 :**

- In write through I am persisting data to HBase.
- For this I inserted 100000 objects in Ignite and then in HBase, Time required for this was around 82 seconds.

**Scenario 2 :**

- I made write-behind property to true.
- I have inserted 100000 objects in Ignite and then in HBase, time required for this was around 124 seconds.

Below are the result.

```
    Write-behind      Objects      Time in ms

     true             1,00,000      81962
     false            1,00,000      123517
```

As per my knowledge, if we are using write-behind cache, it works as an Asynchronous mode
But it is giving unexpected result. Am I going wrong some where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What result are you expecting here? Write-behind mode just schedules store update later, that is much faster than update immediately on each cache change.

To tune it's behavior you may check [setWriteBehindBatchSize](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/mobile/org/apache/ignite/configuration/CacheConfiguration.html#setWriteBehindBatchSize(int)), [setWriteBehindFlushFrequency](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/mobile/org/apache/ignite/configuration/CacheConfiguration.html#setWriteBehindFlushFrequency(long)), [setWriteBehindFlushSize](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/mobile/org/apache/ignite/configuration/CacheConfiguration.html#setWriteBehindFlushSize(int)), [setWriteBehindFlushThreadCount](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/mobile/org/apache/ignite/configuration/CacheConfiguration.html#setWriteBehindFlushThreadCount(int)).

Comment: Thank you responding, Actually I was expecting a faster insertion when write-behind property set to true. But it showed me complete contrast. As write-behind is an Async Operation, It should not wait for Persist data in HBase.

Comment: Write-behind gives smaller latency, but in your case throughput was measured. When unflushed dataset size reaches some threshold (by default 1.5 of `getWriteBehindFlushSize`), store starts working in write-through mode, also flusher threads give additional pressure on GC. Try  to set `setWriteBehindFlushSize` to 100000.

Comment: Write-behind makes insertion into cache faster in terms of latency. Underlying storage update is async and therefore can be delayed, so it can take "longer".

Comment: Thank you for input. I want to benchmark my ignite and hbase. For HBase, I used YCSB. Is there any tool by which I can benchmark Ignite.